# Why is my Shadow Catcher not transparent?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadowcatcher

I'm doing everything I know how to do, but I must be missing something because my shadow catcher isn't working.  It receives a shadow, but instead of becoming transparent, it just gets dark.  (Using Cycles, and I do have Transparent enabled in the Render settings.)

This is my setup:

1. Enable "Shadow Catcher" in the Object Properties
2. Enable "Transparent" in the Render > Film settings
3. Background image > Emission Shader
4. Foreground Object over Shadow Catcher Object
5. HDRI to light the scene

This is what happens:
[image: Example]

Why doesn't the rest of the Shadow Catcher (marked in yellow) become transparent?

I know there is a way to do this in the Compositor, but I would assume it is also possible to set up the scene without having to do that, no?

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/je8tybofioku6yflwvjys/Shadow-Catcher-How.blend?rlkey=rql92n1s5qesmfn6w1irrb1ij&dl=0)

Comment: Is there any reason to have "transparent" turned On eve if you are going to render with a background?

Comment: Hey @Emir, on hindsight, you're right there is no point. I watched a tutorial where someone used the Shadow Catcher (but in a different context) and said 'make sure you have transparent turned on in the Film settings' so I just did this without thinking it through ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you check it closer, you can see checker pattern in black - it means it is transparent ... but shadow catcher does it transparent through entire scene :)

Using shadow catcher feature expects you want to do composition ... so you should mix fg with bg in Compositor.

---

In some scenarios you can try ...

### Cycles

Disable Shadow Catcher and change material of your plane. Here the material is used for back plate and floor plate. The trick here is to use **Window** *Texture Coordinates* for texture mapping.

[image]
[image]

### Eevee

based on your comment ... I don't think there is a native way to do it in Cycles. In Eevee you can trick it by using **Shader to RGB** node (plus under *Material Properties > Settings > Blende mode* set **Alpha Blend** and *Shadow Mod*e set **None**.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just trying to follow your answer: 1) You're saying that you have to do this with compositing.  2) You're saying that I could simply add the background texture to the ground plane object and let the shadow fall onto it.  This would be fine, except that I am building a scene with a background that is set to shadeless (i.e. an emission shader that won't take shadows), and I want to add a shadow onto it with a Shadow Catcher, but without having to use the Compositor.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a solution for you, just another workaround with Eevee (I know you asked for Cycles, but I don't know any other then Compositor). Maybe someone with programming skills to write an OSL shader ...