Shadowcatcher on a plane with a alpha image cuts my torus in half
I have a plane with an alpha image of a building but i only want shadows on the plane from objects landing on it, But were ever my objects intersect with the plane they got cut of.
And if i activate the holdout the shadows disappear

How can i fix this??

Maybe upload your blend file

If you have a chance to use Eevee try this tricky thing ...

For more details see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/311251/2214

I would likes to courage downvoter to briefly comment what is wrong with my answer So I can improve oř explaine. Just a downvoting doesnt help to anybody. Thanks
